# MySql Query to retrieve a a set number from each group

Tags: mysql

If I have the table:

```
------------------
| Provider | ID  |
------------------
| X        | 125 |
------------------
| X        | 133 |
------------------
| X        | 342 |
------------------
| X        | 327 |
------------------
| Y        | 123 |
------------------
| Y        | 853 |
------------------
| Y        | 123 |
------------------
| Z        | 853 |
------------------
| Z        | 533 |
------------------
| Z        | 174 |
------------------
```

I want to get 2 random entries from each of the providers X and Y (ignoring Z) to produce

```
X  id
X  id
Y  id
Y  id
```

I've tried several queries including

```
select id, provider from tableName a where (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName b where b.provider =  a.provider) = 2;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by rand() and limit to 2 with a where clause for x and y and union all the results.  Plainly obvious what you're trying to do and easy to maintain.

```
SELECT Provider, ID
FROM tableName
WHERE provider = 'X'
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 2

UNION ALL

SELECT Provider, ID
FROM tableName
WHERE provider = 'Y'
ORDER BY Rand()
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you try this query:

```
select provider, ID, Rank from 
(
    select *, @row_num := IF(@prev_value=provider,@row_num+1,1) AS rank, @prev_value := provider from 
    (
        select provider, ID, rand() as SortingField from yourTable
        order by provider, SortingField
    ) t1,
    (SELECT @rownum := 0) x, (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
) src
where Rank <= 2 and Provider <> 'Z'
```

Okay, so here's how it works. First thing first, you need random entries so you need to add a "random" sorting field which I did using mySql's `rand()` function. Since it gives a random number, your fields will always be sorted randomly.

This sets us up for the next bit of your requirement which is the two random entries. Since your field are sorted randomly, we'll just pick the first two records which are going to be different every time the query runs. To do that, we're going to need a line counter that resets every time the desired field changes value (in your case, it's 'provider'). So that's what we're doing using variable:

`@rownum` is your row counter and is incremented by 1 every time a new record shows up.

`@prev_value` is your value checker that you use to determine when the counter needs to be reset. Notice that it's set after the `@row_num` incrementation, which is critical because if you set it before, you'd be checking against the current value, which would be pointless.

And at last, all you have to do is select the desired fields (provider, ID, Rank) and grab ranks that are inferior to 2 and ignore the 'Z' provider which is what the last part of the query does.

If you have questions, don't hesitate to ask, but I hope my explanation was clear enough.